# Where are the rules for summoned creatures?

Tags: dnd-4e, summoning

In the PHB1, summoned creatures are very clearly defined in the power descriptions that summon them.  In the PHB2, particularly the Invoker powers, I find many summons such as `Angel of Fire` that do not define all of a summoned creature's attributes, or even how long it persists.

Where can I find this information?  Have these powers been errata'd?

Comment: related: [Does D&D 4e have rules for necromancy or conjuration summoning?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3021/8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Summons** is now its own effect type with general rules surrounding it.

Pg 221 has the info on Summons that you are looking for in the *Player's Handbook 2*

Pg 218 has the same info in the *Player's Handbook 3*